# Clarification on an example contrasting the “BE going to ɪɴꜰɪɴɪᴛɪᴠᴇ” future with the “BE ᴠᴇʀʙ‑ing” future

Tags: tenses, future, progressive-aspect, will-be-going

I’ve been looking at the difference in sentences that express
future events: those using ***“BE going to
ɪɴꜰɪɴɪᴛɪᴠᴇ”*** versus those using ***“BE ᴠᴇʀʙ-ing”***
(sometimes called the present continuous or present progressive).

If I understand correctly, the difference is:

1. The *BE going to ɪɴꜰɪɴɪᴛɪᴠᴇ* form is used for future plans (or events) that are certain:

   *I **am going to study** physics.*
2. The *BE ᴠᴇʀʙ‑ing* (present continuous) form is used for future appointments or arrangements:

   *I **am meeting** Jane on Tuesday.*

One of the comparison examples I found in a video is the following:

| № | Future using *“BE going to ɪɴꜰɪɴɪᴛɪᴠᴇ”* | Future using *“BE ᴠᴇʀʙ‑ing”* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | I **am going to show** her around the town. | I **am showing** her around the town this afternoon. |
| 2 | She **is going to study** Psychology. | She **is studying** Psychology at college next year. |
| 3 | He **is going to see** his lawyer next week. | He **is meeting** his lawyer on Tuesday. |
| 4 | They **are going to meet** again soon. | They **are meeting** at 1 o’clock tomorrow. |

My problem with that table is in the third example:

> He is going to see his lawyer next week.

Why did the presenter use the *BE going to ɪɴꜰɪɴɪᴛɪᴠᴇ* future
in example ⑶  instead of the *BE ᴠᴇʀʙ‑ing* future?

Isn’t this a meeting at a specific date (next week)?

If that sentence is correct, then why does *She is studying Psychology
at college next year.* use the *BE ᴠᴇʀʙ‑ing* present continuous
form?  How does *next week* differ from *next year*?

#### Another quick question

I assume that in *They are going to meet again soon,* it is expressing
the future using *BE going to ɪɴꜰɪɴɪᴛɪᴠᴇ* future because *soon* is
not a specific date to license the *BE ᴠᴇʀʙ‑ing* way of expressing it.

Am I correct?

Comment: I think that "difference" between *"going to" future* and *present continuous* is largely spurious. The main difference is that *I am going to die* automatically implies ***in the future***, whereas *I'm dying* means ***right now***. Admittedly you wouldn't often hear *I'm dying tomorrow*, but the important point is that it's only "future" because of the word ***tomorrow*** (just as in [...for tomorrow we die.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22for+tomorrow+we+die%22))

Comment: If there is a future time stated in the sentence, you can ***either*** use *going to* or present continuous for plans, appointments, or arrangements. The following are all fine: *I am going to show her around the town this afternoon, She is going to study Psychology at college next year, he is going to meet his lawyer on Tuesday, They're going to meet at 1 o'clock tomorrow, He is seeing his lawyer next week.*

Comment: "They are meeting again soon" works fine too, because 'soon' implies the future.  The time doesn't have to be specific, merely in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the present continuous to be used as future, a fairly specific future time needs to be stated (i.e. "someday" would not work). It doesn't have to be so specific, just not totally vague like "someday."

For the "going to" construction, it does not matter if you mention a future time or not, as future is implied. Also you can mention a future time whether specific or not ("someday" works fine).

> I assume They are going to meet again soon. is "Going to" future because "soon" is not a specific date. Correct?

"They are meeting again soon" would actually be fine too, but is not likely to be used often. But "They are meeting again someday" would not. There it would need to be "They are going to meet again someday." Or, of course, you can use the explicit future tense: "They will meet again someday."

A phrase I think is commonly used that is present continuous as future is "I'm moving soon" or "I am moving soon," like in "I'm moving to Dallas soon." So you can use "soon" with present continuous as future.

Answer (score -2):

Going to = is used for personal plans/decisions before the time of speaking. Can be use also for intention and prediction.

Present continuous =used for arrangement or appointment with Time expression or place before the time of speaking.

Will = desicions at the time of speaking.